I created a site with wordpress, now im getting this 403 error, why?

I created a site with wordpress and elementor.
It works for fine for sometime, but now it shows this error.
I dont know how to fix, am i hacked or is this a different problem?
How to resolve this problem, if i got hacked. Do i start from scratch again?
